# Converting candletime to oracle date time

Tags: oracle

I want to convert candletime to  oracle date time. I am using the below query, but it is not giving me the minutes.

```
select (TO_DATE(SUBSTR (1180723052113000, 2, 12),'YY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')) from dual;
```

1180723052113000 is a sample candletime value which means 
Candletime Format = CYYMMddhhmmssSSS
where
C – Century, YY – Year, MM – Month, dd – Day, hh – Hour, mm – Minute, ss – Second, SSS - Milliseconds
CYY - (to be added to 1900 as candle time assumes 1900 as the base)

Need help here!

Comment: I've never heard of Candletime. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/502)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH test_data ( candletime ) AS (
  SELECT '1180723052113000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0180723052113000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0000228010203456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1000229010203456' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(
         TO_CHAR(19 + SUBSTR( candletime, 1, 1 ), '00' )
         || SUBSTR( candletime, 2),
         'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'
       ) AS converted_time
FROM   test_data
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/502/0)**:

```
|          CONVERTED_TIME |
|-------------------------|
|   2018-07-23 05:21:13.0 |
|   1918-07-23 05:21:13.0 |
| 1900-02-28 01:02:03.456 |
| 2000-02-29 01:02:03.456 |
```